# bash array substitution broken on for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, substitution

I have this piece of bash code in a script:

```
[..]
ARRAY=("foo-2" "foo-3" "foo-4")
IGNORE=2
while sleep 2
do
       for ii in "${ARRAY[@]/foo-${IGNORE}/}"
       do
              echo $ii
       done
       [..]
done
```

This piece of code on its own works. But in my full script a weird thing happens:

First loop of sleep runs well. 2nd iteration however, uses the `${ARRAY[@]/foo-${IGNORE}/}` as a literal string. Making a single `echo` command in the `for` loop.

Debugging the for loop:

Works:

```
  for module in ${ARRAY[@]}
```

Also works:

```
  for module in $(echo ${ARRAY[@]} | xargs -n 1 | grep -v foo-${IGNORE})
```

What do you think might be the problem? Is it some sort of bash limitation? Is there any other way you can suggest I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"${ARRAY[@]/foo-${IGNORE}/}"` should expand to multiple elements but one of them would just be an empty string and not completely ignored.

See this:

```
# A=(1 2 3)
# printf '|%s|\n' "${A[@]//1/}"
||
|2|
|3|
```

It also sounds like your array doesn't expand at all. Probably cause of it is that your shell is not being run by Bash.

Anyway better just compare your element instead:

```
   for ii in "${ARRAY[@]}"
   do
          [[ $ii == "foo-$IGNORE" ]] && continue
          echo $ii
   done
```

You can also use globbing:

```
   for ii in "${ARRAY[@]}"
   do
          [[ $ii == *"foo-$IGNORE"* ]] && continue
          echo $ii
   done
```

Comment: Thx. BTW, you're missing a closing `}` in the ARRAY :)